# Как создать эфемерную модель запроса для административной панели Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-admin, redis

У меня есть модель запроса для ChatGPT. Мне нужно сделать ее эфемерной чтобы для нее не нужны были миграции и она не сохранялась в базе данных postgresql, а только в redis, с помощью get - set запросов с ней работать. В админке джанго должно быть поле для быстрого редактирования запроса но без возможности эти запросы добавлять. В теории звучит понятно, но вот с практикой проблемы